# c++: Not able to instanciate boost::archive::text_oarchive or boost::archive::binary_oarchive

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, boost

I have a very short piece of code here, wich won't work.

I think i followed exactly the steps of the documentation.. but i can't get the point, why my code isn't working:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>


TEST(HeaderField2, test2){
std::ofstream ofs("test");
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << "test";
}
```

The error message is the following:

serialize.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveC2ERSoj[_ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveC5ERSoj]+0x25): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/GTest_Serialize.dir/serialize.cpp.o: In Funktion`boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::~text_oarchive_impl()':
serialize.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive18text_oarchive_implINS0_13text_oarchiveEED2Ev[_ZN5boost7archive18text_oarchive_implINS0_13text_oarchiveEED5Ev]+0x2f): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::~basic_text_oprimitive()'
CMakeFiles/GTest_Serialize.dir/serialize.cpp.o: In Funktion`boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive::~common_oarchive()':
serialize.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEED2Ev[_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEED5Ev]+0x1f): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()'
CMakeFiles/GTest_Serialize.dir/serialize.cpp.o: In Funktion`void boost::archive::save_access::end_preamble(boost::archive::text_oarchive&)':
serialize.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive11save_access12end_preambleINS0_13text_oarchiveEEEvRT_[_ZN5boost7archive11save_access12end_preambleINS0_13text_oarchiveEEEvRT_]+0x14): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::end_preamble()'
CMakeFiles/GTest_Serialize.dir/serialize.cpp.o: In Funktion`void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::serialization::collection_size_type const&)':

Can someone explain me, where the error is comming from?

Comment: did you link your program against `boost-serialization` library ?

Comment: Some Boost-libraries are not header-only. Did you link with the required library?

Comment: Thanks so much. This was the problem, after linking, it works.